# Does a Japanese citizen need a visa for European Countries?

Tags: visas, schengen, japanese-citizens

If traveling with a Japanese passport, would you need visas for European countries?
I am a landed immigrant in Canada, traveling from Toronto to Budapest, through Prague and Munich, with Japanese passport.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [EU Visa Policy page](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/index_en.htm) and [documents linked](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2001R0539:20110111:EN:PDF) on it describing and clarifying this policy.  Citizens of Japan are not required to be in possession of a visa to enter Schengen Area (including Hungary, Germany, and Czech Respublic) for a short term stay (<90 days contiunous and 90/180 rule still applies).

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Japanese_citizens)

[image: Visa requirements for Japanese citizens] Source: wikipedia

Comment: Computer says "Noooo"?